# php while loop, when you click vote ajax takes over and grabs row id

Tags: jquery, ajax

Ok here is what i have displayed..

id 1
vote

id 2
vote

id 3
vote

id 4
vote

I'm not sure how to go about this, but what I'd like to do is be able to click on the vote link and ajax take over and update a database.  How would i grab the unique id displayed using jquery?

Thanks,

Comment: can you show your markup? will help with response accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do:

1. User click an item, ajax send request to server
2. Server side detect user's IP, and then decide add/ignore this vote and return a value
3. Update vote display on ajax callback function - depend on the value returned

Comment: But using jquery how can i grab a specific tag and get the proper ID returned by the row listed?